# Handle exception without try/catch

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

I have got a method where the exceptions thrown have to be handled by the caller, and not by the method itself (exceptions specified in the signature and not in the body).
However, in case of something bad happening, I would like to use something similar to a `finally`statement to close my reader before the caller has to deal with the problem.

In the current configuration, if an exception is triggered, the reader remains open.

```
private static void executeFile(Connection c, String fileName) throws SQLException, IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset())); // $JL-I18N$

    /*
        Lot of stuff happen here, and might trigger exceptions
    */

    reader.close();

}
```

Is there a way to handle this case ? Or should the method be refactored to handle exceptions by itself ?

**EDIT**

Some good tips have been provided in the comments. The solution I finally chose considering this was to extract the code triggering the warning and using a try-with-resources.

Comment: Use try-with-resources .

Comment: "I would like to use something similar to a `finally` statement " Why not just that? (Or try-with-resources, of course).

Comment: You can put a finally block with no catch block.

Comment: @AndyTurner Because finally has to be used with a try catch, and I wouldn't like to have like 30 lines of code in my `try`

Comment: @MedAl but this is *exactly* what `finally` is for. If you've got too many lines in the block, extract it to a method.

Comment: You can extract the code within try to a new method. the only one line will be there.

Comment: @AndyTurner And this is EXACTLY why I asked for something similar to `finally`, and not for `finally`

Comment: I would go with a compromise: intercept the exception in your method and re-throw it in the `catch` statement, but *also* have a finally statement (and of course declare your method to throw that exception and document...). This way you still factually delegate exception handling to the caller, but also close your resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it.  Use try-with-resources.

```
private static void executeFile(Connection c, String fileName)
       throws SQLException, IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
        /* Lots of stuff */
    }
}
```

Exceptions thrown in the try block will be propagated, and the reader stack will be closed.  If (hypothetically) the implicit `close()` performed by the try-with-resource was to throw an exception:

- it would be suppressed if another exception already propagating,
- otherwise it would be propagated.

Note that I have rewritten `

```
    new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset())
```

as

```
    new InputStreamReader(is)
```

because they are equivalent: check the javadoc.  The other rewriting was solely for readability, though it does illustrate that try-with-resources can manage multiple resources.